# Setting true/false to if/or statement not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Hey all i have the following js code to validate a textbox:

```
function submitContactUs() {
   var canSubmit = true;

   if (($('#cf_name_txt').val() == "") || ($('#cf_name_txt').val().substr(0, 1) == "*") || ($('#cf_name_txt').length == 1)) {
    if (!$('#cf_name_txt').next('img').length) { //image not there yet
        $('#cf_name_txt').after(theErrorIcon + " id=\"errIcon_cfname\" />");
        $('#errIcon_cfname').vibrate(conf);
        canSubmit = false;
        console.log('false name');
    }
   } else {
    $('#errIcon_cfname').remove();
        console.log('true name');
   }

   if (canSubmit) {
        alert(canSubmit);
        //$("#sendDataContactus").click();
   }
```

When i first click the button to fire off that function i get the correct **false** but once i hit the button again (without changing anything) it for some reason comes back as being **true**??? Does anyone see anything wrong with the js to cause it to do that?

The values i get from the **first button press is**:

```
false name
```

The value i get from the **second button press is**:

```
messagebox saying true
```

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: Whats the purpose of the 2nd level if statement? Couldn't that just be  added to the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click second time you already have `img` tag, so your variable doesn't reset `canSubmit = false;`

Move your variable assigning outside of creating error code block like this:

```
 if (($('#cf_name_txt').val() == "") || ($('#cf_name_txt').val().substr(0, 1) == "*") || ($('#cf_name_txt').length == 1)) {

    canSubmit = false;
    ...
```

Comment: Ah i knew it would be something simple. Thanks Inferpse!